# Using bash and sed

Tags: bash, unix, sed

Okay, so I'm not too great at this, but I have a bash script to pick a random number, then use sed to read lines off of files.
It's not working and I must have done something wrong.  Could anyone correct my code?

I want the code to pull the line (random number) from each of those files, then output it as a single string (with spaces between).

```
NUMBER=$[ ( $RANDOM % 100 )  + 1 ]
sed -n NUMBER'p' /Users/user/Desktop/Street.txt
sed -n NUMBER'p' /Users/user/Desktop/City.txt
sed -n NUMBER'p' /Users/user/Desktop/State.txt
sed -n NUMBER'p' /Users/user/Desktop/Zip.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script will use the *same* randomly chosen number to grab that line from each of the 4 input files you specified and concatenate those lines into a single variable called `$outstring`.

```
#!/bin/bash

NUMBER=$(((RANDOM % 100)+1))

for file in Street City State Zip; do
   outstring+="$(sed -n "${NUMBER}p" "./${file}.txt") "
done

echo $outstring
```

*Note:* If you want (potentially) different line numbers from each of the 4 input files, then simply put the `NUMBER=` statement inside the for-loop.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use `$NUMBER` in your sed commands, rather than just `NUMBER` (or `${NUMBER}` if other text is directly next to it). Example:

```
sed -n "${NUMBER}p" /Users/user/Desktop/Street.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

This has the advantage of choosing from the whole of each file rather than only the first 100 lines. It will choose a different line from each file.

```
for f in Street City State Zip
do
    printf '%s ' "$(shuf -n 1 "/Users/user/Desktop/$f.txt")"
done
printf '\n'
```